# Loops using coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a question about coroutine behaviour in case of loops, see following code extract as example done on a Unity C# script:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(FSM());
}

IEnumerator FSM() {
    state="State1";
    while (true) {
        Debug.Log("State "+state);
        yield return StartCoroutine(state);
    }
}

IEnumerator State1() {
    while (true) {
        if (stateTransitionCond) {
            state = "NextState";
            yield break;
        }
        yield return null; 
    }
}
```

The status machine works fine, but while the current status is Status1 (`stateTransitionCond==false`), due to the `yield return null` inside the loop of `State1()` routine, I was expecting that loop inside `FMS()` also performs another iteration generating debug log 'Debug.Log("State "+state);'.

In other words I was expecting a lot of debug log (one for each iteration of State1() routine, when status is Status1) but in the reality only 1 execution is performed while status is Status1.

So I suppose I miss something about yield functionality, is there anybody that can explain me this behaviour?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue stems from the fact that your code does not break out of the `State1()` method until `stateTransitionCond == true`.

The method starting the coroutine, `FSM()`, is not returned to until `State1` is finished. In other words, control flow does not return to the calling method until the coroutine is complete. I believe this is due to the fact that you are `yield`-ing `State1` inside `FSM` (yielding another coroutine). Obviously, "normal" methods do not wait for the coroutine to finish before continuing execution.

Please see the code sample below for an illustrative example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoroutineTest : MonoBehaviour {
    // current FSM state
    public string state = ""; 

    void Start()
    {   
        StartCoroutine(FSM());
    }   

    IEnumerator FSM()
    {   
        state = "State1";

        while (true)
        {   
            Debug.Log("State: " + state);
            // ExecuteOnce will execute exactly once before returning to the outer function
            yield return StartCoroutine(ExecuteOnce());

            // ExecuteIndefinitely will execute indefinitely until its while() loop is broken
            // uncomment to test
            //yield return StartCoroutine(ExecuteIndefinitely());
        }   
    }   

    IEnumerator ExecuteOnce()
    {   
        Debug.Log("Calling ExecuteOnce()");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }   

    IEnumerator ExecuteIndefinitely()
    {   
        Debug.Log("Calling ExecuteIndefinitely()");
        while (true)
        {   
            Debug.Log("Inside ExecuteIndefinitely()");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }   
    }   
}
```